# Issue using cons function in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, append

I am learning Lisp and I had to write a function whose return value was a list containing the odd integers (if any) from the given input. In code I have this:

```
(defun f3 (a)
   (cond
    ((null a) nil )
    ((and (numberp (car a)) (oddp (car a))) (cons (car a) (f3 (cdr a))))
    (T (f3 (cdr a)))
   ) ; end cond
)
```

I originally wanted to use the append function, but I kept getting errors.

It was recommended to me to use cons function. When I did this my function started working (code is above). I originally had this:

```
(defun f3 (a)
    (cond
       ((null a) ())
       ((and (numberp (car a)) (oddp (car a))) (append (f3 (cdr a)) (car a))))
       (T (append () (f3 (cdr a))))
    )
)
```

but kept getting errors. For example, if I called `(f3 '(1 2 3))` it would say "error 3 is not type LIST". So, my questions are why does cons work here and why did append not work? How does cons work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`append` wants list arguments, and `(car a)` is not a list. Instead of `(car a)` you'd need `(list (car a))`. In other words, `(append (f3 (cdr a)) (list (car a)))`.

That will basically work, but you'll get the result in reverse order. So that should be `(append (list (car a)) (f3 (cdr a)))`.

Also note that your `(append () (f3 (cdr a)))` is equivalent to just `(f3 (cdr a))`.

The resulting changes in your original would be:

```
(defun f3 (a)
    (cond
       ((null a) ())
       ((and (numberp (car a)) (oddp (car a))) 
          (append (list (car a)) (f3 (cdr a)))))
       (T (f3 (cdr a)))))
```

But, you wouldn't normally use `append` to prepend a single element to a list. It would more naturally be done using `cons`. So

```
  (append (list (car a)) (f3 (cdr a)))
```

Is more appropriately done by:

```
  (cons (car a) (f3 (cdr a)))
```

Which finally takes you right to the working version you showed.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. This was a well written answer.

Answer (score 5):

While something like [mbratch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884202/1281433) will help you in learning about list manipulation (and so is probably a more useful answer for you *at this point in your study*), it's also important to learn about the standard library of the language that you're using.  In this case, you're trying to filter out everything except odd numbers.  Using [remove-if-not](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm), that's just:

```
(defun keep-odd-numbers (list)
  (remove-if-not (lambda (x)
                   (and (numberp x) (oddp x)))
                 list))
```

```
CL-USER> (keep-odd-numbers '(1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e))
;=> (1 3 5)
```

Comment: Well-stated Josh (+1). Indeed, I was glossing over an optimal solution in favor of explaining the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a fix to your actual problem, which @mbratch provided, here's the way I would implement something like this using the LOOP macro (another part of the standard library):

```
(defun keep-odd-numbers (list)
  (loop for x in list collecting x when (and (numberp x) (oddp x))))
```

Comment: Or `when (and (numberp x) (oddp x)) collect x` (`loop` is very flexible :)).